# Store record values before update

Tags: controller, class, commandbutton, update, loop

I have a requirement to allow User Rollback the Updates here by one click on a commandbutton. That feature I have tried to tackle by Revert Changes button here . Is there any other way to deal with it? I found from different questions that Set Savepoint would not work here to roll back. Is there any other alternative?Here is my code snippet. It can't store list values before update.

Class snippet::

```
Public List<Incident_abv__c> RevertList{
    get{
        if(RevertList== null) RevertList= new List<Incident_abv__c>();
        return RevertList;
    }
    set;


  public void enableCloseDateInput(){
        disableInput = true;

        if(RevertList!=null)
        {


        update  RevertList;
         system.Debug('Saikat'+RevertList);
         revertList.clear();
         }

    }

  Public pagereference readcsvFile(){
       showReload=true;

       csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
       csvfilelines = csvAsString.split('\n');
       Integer filei=csvfilelines.size();
       system.debug('saikat'+'@'+csvfilelines);
       inputvalues = new String[]{};
       for(string st:csvfilelines[0].split(','))
           fieldList.add(st);  
      sObjectlist.clear();

       for(Integer i=1;i<csvfilelines.size();i++){
           //Incident_abv__c inc= new Incident_abv__c() ;

           string[] csvRecordData = csvfilelines[i].split(',');
           system.debug('saikat'+'@'+csvRecordData[0] );
         for(Integer j=0;j<csvRecordData.size();j++)  {
         //public List<Incident_abv__c > inc{get;set;} 
         if(String.isNotEmpty(csvRecordData[j]) || String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[j]) )
         { 

         for(Incident_abv__c  inc : [select Name,Id from Incident_abv__c where name=:csvRecordData[j]])
           {if(inc.name == csvRecordData[j])            
              {
             // if(disableinput==false)
              RevertList.add(inc);

              inc.status_abv__c = 'Open';
           inc.Report_Publish_Date_abv__c = Date.today();
            if(inc.Rep_abv__c !=null)
                inc.OwnerId = inc.Rep_abv__c; 
              }
              else { ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Your Incident Name::'+csvRecordData[j]+' does not exist.'));

                   }


           //if(!sObjectList.contains(inc))  
           //sObjectlist.clear();                                                                        
           sObjectList.add(inc);
           system.debug('saikat'+inc.name) ;
          // break;
           } 
         }
                                                       }
           system.debug('saikat'+sObjectlist.size()) ;
           update sObjectlist;

           //sObjectlist.clear();



       }

      return null;
  }
```

Comment: SFDC_GEEK -- as you are a frequent poster, you should know by now that indicating what doesn't work with associated detail is kind of a best practice when posting questions if you want the maximum community response. All you state is `it fails` -- the community is good but can't read minds

Comment: I am sorry if I have wrongly stated. Would keep it in mind. Thanks! Can you please help me in this requirement?